# Phonegap Parse.com plugin not saving installation

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, phonegap-plugins

hi i am trying to use the phonegap parse plugin-
https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin 
i created a new phonegap project added the plugin
but it is not working.i have created a git repository please see my index.html in www folder https://github.com/mshukla19/Parse-Phonegap-Plugin
it shows me success and even shows me an installation id in alert but then parse.com shows no installation is present

Comment: It would be better to narrow down your problem and be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so figured it out.if you want to use phonegap with parse but need the installation id in javascript then use -
https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin 
in your index.js initialize the plugin.make sure you do it in the ondeviceready function.if you still need help then check my demo repo-
https://github.com/mshukla19/Parse-Phonegap-Plugin
once you have installation id you can use js sdk of parse to create user or store data